# What does 'close invalidated' mean

Tags: discussion, terminology

Recently I flagged [Align views in a relative layout to the bottom of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37214918/2160877) as a duplicate. A few days later, when I checked it again to see if it was closed, I realized it wasn't.

Searching in Meta brought me to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322613/questions-flagged-as-duplicate-being-disputed), where a comment suggested checking the timeline. So I checked the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37214918/timeline) and saw that the **close** flag was set as **invalidated**.

Does this mean that it was disputed? When I click on it I see only *"This item is no longer reviewable."* Do I need more reputation (3000+ ?) to view more detailed information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, to be clear, the close item you are seeing in the timeline **is not your flag**. It is a review task which was created based on your flag. Your flag is currently still active, but may eventually age away if no action is ever taken with the question. You can see the status of your flags in your flagging history by clicking on the number of helpful flags you've raised in your profile.

The review task itself was invalidated because it only had 1 vote or flag on it, and it sat in the review queue for several days and no one ever took one single action on it. Either they were skipping it or just plain not seeing it. In order to keep the queue number down on Stack Overflow, tasks which only have one vote or flag and don't see any action simply get removed from review. If the question ever gets another flag on it, then it will re-enter the close queue with a bit more weight and hopefully someone will actually look at it. The act of these review tasks being invalidated has absolutely no effect on the status of your flag.

Answer (score 4):

It means the user retracted their close vote, or the close vote timed out (and was therefore retracted by the system).

In this case because the question was edited and a comment added explaining why it was not a duplicate. The close voter may have accepted that explanation and rescinded their vote.

The item is no longer reviewable because there are no close votes on it any more.

Comment: The edited question matches even closer the duplicated one. During my discussion with the OP in the comments, it seems the OP agreed with my point of view. A few days later the flag is set as **invalidated**.