# Why do some close or reopen votes show in a timeline as invalidated instead of completed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen, timeline

**Preface**:

This question is, IMO, not a duplicate of "[What does 'close invalidated' mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279553/286501)", for these reasons:

- Only bullet "1." of my question seems to be partially addressed in the above question, which doesn't talk about **`reopen voting`** in any way (only about **`close voting`**).
- The above question does ot explain anything about bullet "2." and "3." of my question.
- The above question in no way addresses the scenario related to example C, where the real answer to that part of my question is included in the comment quoted near the end of my question.

---

Assume a question which was put on hold as the result of voting via the *Close votes* review queue (on any SE site), as shown in [this question's timeline](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/231736/timeline#review_94274): below the link to the actual [close votes review result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/close/94274), it shows the typical (in red) "`completed`".

Similar for the result of voting via the *Reopen votes* review queue (on any SE site), as shown in [the same question's timeline](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/231736/timeline#review_94305): below the link to the actual [reopen votes review result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/94305), it shows the typical (in red) "`completed`".

However, there are questions where such "`completed`" is not shown:

- Example A where below the [close votes review result](https://devops.stackexchange.com/posts/226/timeline#review_147) it says "`invalidated`" (not "`completed`"):
- Example B where below the [reopen votes review result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/195362/timeline#review_94495) it says "`invalidated`" (not "`completed`"):
- Example C where below the [reopen votes review result](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/203917/timeline#review_80831) it says "`invalidated`" (not "`completed`"):

My questions:

1. What does such "`invalidated`" **actually mean**?
2. What are **possible cases** where this happens?
3. **Who** or what actually "invalidates" such reviews of close or reopen votes, and **why**?

**Update 1**:

My "impression" is that something happens (gets triggered) by a moderator-like intervention, maybe something like "stop this close/reopen voting" and my (next) guess is that such event then pulls the "invalidated" trigger. I may be wrong (just guessing), but that is what I saw happening in various similar cases over the recent past (and via this question I try to understand if there is such a thing, and if so what it is).

**Update 2**:

The existing answer to my question here, appears to be an answer for Example A and B. But IMO it does stil not explain Example C. So until an even better answer arrives that also explains Example C, I accept this answer.

**Update 3**:

Note this comment below the accepted answer:

> Sorry, I misread the dates. That one got invalidated because of a bug that existed back then (I believe it got fixed last year). Essentially any reopen vote causes the edit to be ignored, but the system only considered reopen votes at least 15 minutes old for review cases. So if the system updated review within that 15-minute, it would think the task is invalid because the edit doesn't qualify and the only reopen vote isn't old enough. It would kill the task and wouldn't recreate it unless a second reopen vote came in. I forget how it was fixed, I think we started ignoring the reopen vote time.

Only this comment should illustrate what I wrote in my "Preface" above ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the review task was still ongoing when the question got either closed or reopened. Now that the action is already completed, there is no point in continuing the review process for it - so the task gets invalidated to prevent further reviews. Review tasks are only ever marked as completed when the final review is what causes the action to actually take place.

So if you vote to close from review and that vote causes the question to get closed, the review task is marked as completed.

If you vote to close from the question page and that causes the question to get closed, the review task gets marked as invalidated.

The review queues operate by choosing posts which match a certain set of criteria and then creating a task for them. If those conditions are no longer met at some point (e.g. because the question got closed) then the system eventually removes the task because it doesn't qualify for the queue anymore. This happens across all queues and there are various criteria that can dequeue posts from each queue (see [a somewhat outdated list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581)).

All of this is done automatically by the system via the same processes that create the tasks. There is no button anyone, including staff, can push to just manually invalidate tasks with no other action.

Comment: merci! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't understand (yet) how it  answers my bullet "3." (about the who and why part of it). My GUESS is that it's a moderator who triggers something. And more info on that?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens The system does it. The same process that creates new tasks for eligible posts also invalidates tasks for now-ineligible posts. It's done automatically.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens No such thing exists. Moderators have no power to invalidate tasks directly. Not even staff can do that. We *can* cause circumstances that make the system to invalidate them in certain situations, like going in and declining a NAA flag to invalidate the low quality posts review task. But that's a roundabout way that requires the moderator to actually complete some sort of action. There's not just a button anyone can push.

Comment: can you please MOVE your last comment into your answer (not sure if you know, but "mods" may come along and destroy all comments ... happens to me lots of times on "some" other site). PS: I'm going to integrate/move (part of) my comments here in my actual question also.

Comment: I've been rereading your answer multiple times, and maybe I start to understand what you really mean ... about your 3rd parg, with "if you vote to close ...": is it important (does it matter) if the user who does that is yes or no a mod? Because if a mod joins the review process somehow, whatever the mod votes is the verdict, right? So maybe THAT is what I am actually looking for?

Comment: @Pierre Sure, if a mod choose Leave Open or votes to close then their action is binding and the review task completes. But that doesn't invdalidate the task as you describe. It actually completes the task.

Comment: Sorry but still there has to be something/somewhere (which I suspect to be triggered somehow via a mod). To refine the "invalidated" scenario: assume the mod did NOT explicitely use the close/reopen votes review queue to indicate his/her vote (because that results in "completed" of course). Is there anything else a mod may do (which a non-mod cannot see in any way) that would be equivalent to such vote from a mod via the review queue? Similar to how a mod can reopen (or put on hold) a question without even using the vote to reopen (or put on hold) queue?

Comment: @pierre No there isn't.

Comment: As you must have noticed, I accepted this answer "for now". But as per my update 2 I think Example C is not explained by your answer (please correct me if I am wrong). Do you think I should post a followup question (with link to your answer) to also sort out Example C? Note: I bet I can find a dozen of Example C questions ...

Comment: What's confusing about it? Your reopen vote aged away, so there were zero reopen votes and thus the question was no longer eligible for review (because the edit stopped mattering once you cast a reopen vote), so the system killed off the task.

Comment: "aged away" ... already after about 5 mins after I voted to reopen??? WHY did that happen ... so fast? That is the core of my question ... Note: my edit happened about 15 mins BEFORE I could vote on the question when I saw it showing up in the review queue

Comment: Sorry, I misread the dates. That one got invalidated because of a bug that existed back then (I believe it got fixed last year). Essentially any reopen vote causes the edit to be ignored, but the system only considered reopen votes at least 15 minutes old for review cases. So if the system updated review within that 15-minute, it would think the task is invalid because the edit doesn't qualify and the only reopen vote isn't old enough. It would kill the task and wouldn't recreate it unless a second reopen vote came in. I forget how it was fixed, I think we started ignoring the reopen vote time

Comment: ***bingo !!!*** ... sorry for insisting ... would you now please want to INVALIDATE the close voting of my question also??? Maybe also integrate your prior comment in your answer (or do you rather want me to post an etra answer to complete yours (related to Example C))?

Comment: Sorry to come back to this "issue" again. But can you please have a look at [this timeline](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/234666/timeline), about something that happened in the past hour or so. Long story short: it happened AGAIN ... which makes me wonder if that's still that same bug you referred to (maybe due to some type of regression or so?), or if it may have been "something else".

Comment: @Pierre You might wanna file a bug report for the Reopen queue incorrectly invalidating tasks when a reopen vote comes in after an edit.

Comment: It seems [there is already such a report](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3348), with an answer by Shog. cc @Pierre.Vriens

Comment: merci @Gerry for your comment , I integrated it in my question I just posted (with credits to you of course). So you know about all meta question on all SE sites???